# cocos2d code slow down after some time

Tags: iphone, ios4, cocos2d-iphone

all
I am making a game in cocos2d, and I am moving an object from one place to another , throught CCTouchBegan , CCTouchMoved, CCTouchEneded (ccp function) and after that I take the action on it.
Any thoughts on why this code runs slow on device but fast on simulator in iphone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show us the code then we can say something particular. 
But I think you just forgot to stop the action. [object stopAction]; 
or can use this method [self removeChild:(CCSprite*)sender cleanup:YES] It will also cleanup all running actions depending on the cleanup parameter

Comment: Good suggestion.  Yes We'd really have to see more of the code to make any kind of assessment.  What is the code you are using from moving an object from one place to another?  You may want to profile your code using Instruments to possibly get an idea of where most of your work is being done.  Can you work backwards to a previous point in your code where things were running fast for you?

Answer (score 0):

Code often runs slower on the device than it does in the simulator.  The simulator is not accurate with respect to performance.  In order to gauge how fast something executes, you have to try it on a device.

Answer (score 0):

check your memory allocations.

am also having same problem. bcoz of memory management . now i solved.

check your memory leakage using performance tool in your xcode.